# Write bidimensional array into a binary file

Tags: arrays, c, binary

EDITED

I am trying to write a bidimensional array into a binary file (cop_bin), and I should use fwrite function in the    //SAVE ARRAY INTO A BINARY FILE  part.

I have used fwrite but it's not working.

As for now I have this code that works perfectly to save data from csv to the array, but now I need to save the array into the binary file.

So far, the code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int muestraMenu ();
void opcion0 (int matriz[699][13]);

int main ()
{
  int opcion = 8;
  int matriz[699][13];

  do
    {
      opcion = muestraMenu ();
      switch (opcion)
    {
    case 0:
      printf (" 0. Configuración e inicialización");
      opcion0 (matriz);
      break;
    case 8:
      break;
    }
    }
  while (opcion != 8);

  return 0;
}

void opcion0 (int matriz[699][13])
{
  int datos[13];
 // int matriz[699][13];
  int i;
  int a[100];
  int x = 0;
  char line[100];
  FILE *f = fopen ("bcancer.csv", "r");
  FILE *cop_bin;

  if (f == NULL)
    {
      printf ("error abriendo el fichero bcancer.csv\n");
      return;
    }
  printf ("\n");
  //Recorremos fichero para guardar datos en un array bidimensional
  while (fgets (line, sizeof line, f))
    {
      if (sscanf (line, "%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d",
          &datos[0], &datos[1], &datos[2], &datos[3], &datos[4],
          &datos[5], &datos[6], &datos[7], &datos[8], &datos[9],
          &datos[10], &datos[11], &datos[12]) == 13)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
          matriz[x][i] = datos[i];
        }

      x++;
      //datos guardados correctamente
    }
      else
    {
      printf ("Datos no válidos");
    }

      //SAVE ARRAY INTO A BINARY FILE
    fwrite(matriz,sizeof(double),1,cop_bin);
    fclose(cop_bin);

    }
```

Could you give me a little help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suspect [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite), and [`fclose`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose) are probably on the agenda at some point. Examples of how to use all of the above are amply available.

Comment: Edited now with fwrite. No compile errors but when I run it the program stops.

Comment: You obviously know that you must open files before you can perform any operation. You do it for `f` but why don't you open a file for `cop_bin`? That pointer is just uninitialized.